# Why am I constantly getting a 502 Bad Gateway error?

Tags: error

My Tor was working perfectly a couple days ago, but now all of the sudden, I can't access any websites. Whenever I try to go to any .onion site, it gives me a '502 Bad Gateway' error. I've tried resetting my computer, my router, reinstalling Tor- nothing has been working. I'm not sure what the problem is.
[image]

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a Tor error, but rather a problem with the onion service you are trying to access.

Comment: Try some know good services: such as facebook (https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/) or the tor project (http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion/).